How to show multipart/form-data with a file upload field in swagger ui with Rust utoipa?
I am trying to add openapi for my Rust axum app with utoipa, and the example code for multipart form and file uploading didn't work for me. see https://docs.rs/utoipa/latest/utoipa/attr.path.html#defining-file-uploads. The example code is in https://github.com/Geekstime-Rust-F/axum-multipart-form-utoipa-demo.
Main code block:
#[utoipa::path(
    post,
    path = "/upload",
    request_body(content_type = "multipart/formdata", content = UploadedFile, description = "File to upload"),
    responses(
        (status = 200, description = "OK")
    )
)]
async fn upload() -> impl IntoResponse {
    todo!()
}

When I visit http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/#/default/upload, I saw
choose file button do not show
Add integer item is there, however I am expecting an upload file button like
choose file button like this.
I also googled online and tried https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/19dki68/axum_utoipa_utoipaswaggerui_how_to_let_utoipa/ but still not working.

There's a typo in the code - multipart/formdata should be multipart/form-data (with a hyphen). Not sure if that's what causes the problem though.

Thanks, Helen. Unfortunately multipart/form-data didn't work as expected as well.
